# Generate php source code based on php array

Tags: php, performance, code-generation, shared-hosting

I've got a non-modifiable function which takes several seconds to finish.
The function returns an array of objects. The result only changes about once per day.

To speed things up I wanted to cache the result using APC but the hosting provider(shared hosting environment) does not offer any memory caching solutions (APC, memcache, ...).

The only solution I found was using serialize() to store the data into a file and then deserializing the data back again.

What about generating php source code out of the array? Later I could simple call

```
require data.php
```

to get the data into a predefined variable.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Storing the resulting .html is no option because the output is user-dependant.

Comment: Will your provider allow your program to modify its scripts as it runs, if you aren't logged in? If I were the provider, I'd be tempted to disallow this on the grounds it might prevent virus troubles.

Comment: @Ira: PHP-scripts are ascii files and so they are treated as data and not as executable. A server can not distinguish between data you write to a file (lets say a configuration file, or something like a very simple database or stuff) and data you write to a file, that is later parsed by the PHP interpreter.

Comment: As far as I know there are no restrictions. Generating php files on the fly should be ok!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
// File: data.php
<?php
return array(
  32,
  42
);


// Another file
$result = include 'data.php';
var_dump($result);
```

This is already possible. To update your file, you can use something like this

```
file_put_contents('data.php', '<?php return ' . var_export($array, true) . ';');
```

Update:
However, there is also nothing wrong with serialize()/unserialize() and storing the serialized array into a file.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just cache the resulting html page that is generated? You could do that fairly simply:

```
// Check to see if cached file exists
// You could run a crob job to delete this at a certain time
// or have the cache file expire after a set amount of time
if(file_exists('cache.html')) {
  include('cache.html');
  exit;
}

ob_start(); // start capturing output buffer

// do output

$output = ob_get_contents();
$handle = fopen('cache.html', 'w');
fwrite($handle, $output);
fclose($handle);

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: completely valid and performant solution based on the information I provided in the question - but the output is user dependant - I updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just write the answers to a database, and use the function arguments as  key.